# How do you replace all the occurrences of a words from a multi-line string which is user defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, python-3.8

[image showing my output code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD3eQ.jpg)

I would like to replace the occurrence of word from the user-defined string with some other word that I input into my program.

```
lines = []
#getting multi-line input from the user
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
text = '\n'.join(lines)
print(text)

# word count
total_char = 0                      #total char
total_w = 1                         #total words
for i in range(len(text)):
    if(text[i] == ' ' or text[i] == '\n'):
         total_w += 1         
print("Total no. of words: ",total_w)

#char count
for j in range(len(text)):
    total_char += 1
print("The total number of characters: ",total_char)
```

Here is my program output image. I just wanna count the occurrence of the repeated word from user input and replace it by some other random word.

Comment: Is your program working? any sample test cases?

Comment: yeah, I have just now added the output code you can have a look now 